# how to display my users from firebase using angularjs

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

**i'm trying to display the names of my users in a list using angularjs.**
already tried to look for an answer in the docs.

```
"users" : {
    "simplelogin:24" : {
      "age" : "24",
      "email" : "a@a.com",
      "gender" : "male",
      "location" : "USA",
      "name" : "IY"
    },
    "simplelogin:25" : {
      "age" : "21",
      "email" : "girl@girls.com",
      "gender" : "female",
      "location" : "USA",
      "name" : "iris"
    }
  }
```

here what i'm trying to do:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp.home', ['firebase.auth', 'firebase', 'firebase.utils', 'ngRoute']);

  app.controller('HomeCtrl', ['usersList','$scope', 'fbutil', 'user', '$firebaseObject', 'FBURL',
    function (usersList, $scope, fbutil, user, $firebaseObject, FBURL) {
    $scope.syncedValue = $firebaseObject(fbutil.ref('syncedValue'));
    $scope.user = user;
    $scope.FBURL = FBURL;
    $scope.users = usersList;
  }]);

  app.factory('usersList', ['fbutil', '$firebaseArray',
   function(fbutil, $firebaseArray) {
    var ref = fbutil.ref('users').limitToLast(50);
    return $firebaseArray(ref);
  }]);
```

and:

```
<ul><li ng-repeat='user in users'>{{user.name}}</li></ul>
```

Comment: Where's your angularjs code?

Comment: i posted my code hope you can understand better

Comment: I think your `object array` is not organize. E.g. `simplelogin:24` and `simplelogin:25`. You need to have `key` and `value`. E.g. `simplelogin` is the `key` and `24` is the value.

Comment: The `users` object/array will not work using `ng-repeat`. It has different `key`. `simplelogin:25` and `simplelogin:24`.

Comment: What is the problem here? What you have looks solid. You can certainly use `users` in an ng-repeat to display the names. You haven't mentioned an error or issue. Also, you didn't mention what fbutil is or the fact that you're using angularFire-seed. If you don't include relevant info, it's going to be hard for anybody to help you reach a resolution.

Answer (score 1):

Most basic way to get the users and show them:

```
    var app = angular.module('myApp.home', [])

      app.factory('usersList', function(fbutil, $firebaseArray) {
        //Get the firebase reference
        var ref = fbutil.ref('users');
        //return the array of users
        return $firebaseArray(ref);
      });

      app.controller('HomeCtrl', function (usersList, $scope) {
        //Put the users array in the scope.users
        $scope.users = usersList;
      });
```

And the ng-repeat just stays the same.

Comment: This looks the same as what OP has in his example code, although that may have been added after you answered.

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't put an angularJS code, I don't know how to fix your code.

However, I can inform about 'how to display the name property of firebase object.'

```
    var ref = new Firebase(your firebase url);
    var userOne = $firebaseObject(ref.child('users').child('simplelogin:24'));
    userOne.$loaded(function(){
                console.log(userOne.name);
              });
    var userTwo = $firebaseObject(ref.child('users').child('simplelogin:25'));
    userTwo.$loaded(function(){
    console.log(userTwo.name);
});
```

I hope this code is what you wanted.

And, you have read the doc of angularFire?

https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html

Give it a try!

Comment: Can you try it like this ? 
(1)
$scope.users = usersList.$loaded().then(function(){ return usersList; }); 

OR
(2)
$scope.users = usersList;

what's your problem exactly?

Comment: @nujabes you can't return a value from an asynchronous function being passed into another method. In this case, $scope.users would be the promise, not the returned value.